# Excel recorded SQL database query not working

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I've recorded a macro to query a database, and when I record the macro, the query runs properly.  However, when I try to run the macro again on the same sheet or on a different one, I get the error:

> runtime error 1004, "SQL syntax error"

on the line

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False".
```

Below is the recorded macro.

```
Sub Macro3()

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "ODBC;DSN=Substation Prod;SRVR=SUBP;UID=U326357;",     Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .CommandText = Array( _
        "SELECT FACT_MONTHLY.TIME_STAMP, FACT_MONTHLY.SYSTEM_NUMBER_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.SUBSTATION_NUMBER_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.MVA_MAX_OUT_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.MW_MAX_OUT_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.MVAR_MAX_OUT_VAL0, FACT_" _
        , _
        "MONTHLY.MW_MIN_OUT_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.MVAR_MIN_OUT_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PF_MAX_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PF_MIN_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.TOP_OIL_TANK_MAX_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.LOAD_FACTOR_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH1_TAP_MAX" _
        , _
        "_DRAG_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.WIND_TEMP_MAX_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.LTC_TEMP_MAX_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH2_TAP_MAX_DRAG_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH3_TAP_MAX_DRAG_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.BOT_OIL_TEMP_MAX_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH" _
        , _
        "1_TAP_MIN_DRAG_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH2_TAP_MIN_DRAG_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH3_TAP_MIN_DRAG_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH1_LOAD_MAX_KV_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH2_LOAD_MAX_KV_VAL0, FACT_MONTHLY.PH3_LOAD_MAX_KV_VAL0, FA")
        .Name = "Query from Substation Prod"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I've searched online for ways to fix this issue, but none of the other solutions I've found are working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried this in a sql editor to see if it works there?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Excel QueryTables.add .Refresh BackgroundQuery Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559644/vba-excel-querytables-add-refresh-backgroundquery-error)

Comment: no it doesn't work in an sql editor, and I looked into microsoft query, and viewed the SQL statement, and the entire statement isn't included in the recorded macros.  For some reason, the end of it, the portion specifiying how to sort the data and between what time periods I want, has been cut off from the macro.  I'm adding it back now to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous lines inside the With statement are setting properties.
 the

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery := False
```

is a method call.

The refresh is supposed to refresh the results.
 The background Query is for when quering SQL data and is optional so I think you can leave it off and just have .Refresh

For further assistance try [VBA Excel QueryTables.add .Refresh BackgroundQuery Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559644/vba-excel-querytables-add-refresh-backgroundquery-error)